# Count the number of viewed pages that contain an exact string

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I would like to count the number of viewed pages that contain some customer tagging, my code is currently returning the same value for all 3 counts and these values are far too high, can anyone suggest what the issue is here?

```
SELECT
  Date,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN hits.page.pagepath LIKE "?aff=" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Affinity,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN hits.page.pagepath LIKE "?aff2=" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Addon_Affinity,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN hits.page.pagepath LIKE "?aff3=" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Style_Affinity

FROM `dataset.ga_sessions_*` AS t
  CROSS JOIN UNNEST(hits) AS hits
WHERE (_TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20170703' AND '20170703')
group by date
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other possibility would be to solve this query like:

```
WITH data AS(
  select "20170701" as date, ARRAY<STRUCT<page STRUCT<pagePath STRING> >> [STRUCT(STRUCT('?aff=' as pagePath) as page), STRUCT(STRUCT('?aff=' as pagePath) as page), STRUCT(STRUCT('/test' as pagePath) as page), STRUCT(STRUCT('?aff2=' as pagePath) as page), STRUCT(STRUCT('?aff=' as pagePath) as page)] hits union all
  select "20170701" as date, ARRAY<STRUCT<page STRUCT<pagePath STRING> >> [STRUCT(STRUCT('?aff2=' as pagePath) as page), STRUCT(STRUCT('?aff2=' as pagePath) as page), STRUCT(STRUCT('?aff3=' as pagePath) as page), STRUCT(STRUCT('?aff3=' as pagePath) as page), STRUCT(STRUCT('?aff=' as pagePath) as page)] hits
)

SELECT
  date,
  sum((select countif(hits.page.pagepath like "?aff=") from unnest(hits) hits)) Affinity,
  sum((select countif(hits.page.pagepath like "?aff2=") from unnest(hits) hits)) Addon_Affinity,
  sum((select countif(hits.page.pagepath like "?aff3=") from unnest(hits) hits)) Style_Affinity
FROM data
GROUP BY
date
```

Where `data` is a simulation of your `ga_sessions` data.

Comment: Hi Will - this is running but only returning a very small count (4,3,2), any idea why it's not counting all the pages?

Comment: I created simulated `data` just as an example. In your query you should adapt it to query over your data set, that is, your `FROM` clause should be `FROM `[tablename].ga_sessions_*` AS t WHERE (_TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20170703' AND '20170703')`

Answer (score 1):

COUNT will increase its sum by one if its input is not null. You should use SUM or COUNTIF instead:

```
SELECT
  Date,
  COUNTIF(hits.page.pagepath LIKE "?aff=") AS Affinity,
  COUNTIF(hits.page.pagepath LIKE "?aff2=") AS Addon_Affinity,
  COUNTIF(hits.page.pagepath LIKE "?aff3=") AS Style_Affinity
FROM `[tablename].ga_sessions_*` AS t
  CROSS JOIN UNNEST(hits) AS hits
WHERE (_TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20170703' AND '20170703')
group by date
```

Comment: Thanks Elliot, I have tried this and it's returning different counts for each string, as expected. However the counts are higher than they should be - is there something in my query that is counting more than it should?

Comment: Well, it depends on what you're trying to count. This query counts every page for every visitor. Maybe you're trying to count just the number of visitors, but it isn't clear from the question that you posted.

Comment: I'd like to only count the pages where the ?aff tracking was present. Do you know how I could adjust to do this?

Comment: If you are trying to count pages--that is what the query that I posted does.